# wcf c# erro ao acessar diretório

Tags: c#, wcf

Estou escrevendo um serviço **WCF** usando c#. Em um dos meus métodos eu tento acessar um diretório na rede (qualquer comando como `directory.Exists()` ou `directory.GetFiles()`) e recebo o seguinte erro:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]: Nome de usuário ou senha
>   incorretos.

Se tento acessar o mesmo diretório a partir de uma aplicação **Web API** funciona normalmente. Alguém já teve esse problema e poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Isso rodando local ou publicado no servidor? pode ser devido a diferença de credenciais entre uma aplicação e outra.

Comment: Tentei rodar tanto localmente quanto num servidor e recebo o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 1):

O serviço **WCF** estava mostrando uma mensagem de erro genérica, mudei para mostrar um mensagem mais especifica e descobri que era problema de usuário conforme disseram anteriormente, para resolver isso criei um usuário na minha máquina e um usuário na máquina de destino com as mesmas credenciais. Após alterei o **DefaultAppPool** do **IIS** para usar o usuário que criei. Assim foi possível acessar os diretórios.